# MonoTouch object reference preventing garbage collection

Tags: memory-leaks, xamarin.ios, garbage-collection

I am having a weird issue that is causing a memory leak in MonoTouch. Here is my setup.

```
CaseTabController - UITabBarController
-- CaseMediaItemsController - UIViewController
-- CaseInfoController (irrelevant) - UIViewController
```

The child controllers are displayed as tabs. From the child controllers, I am trying to add some `NavigationItem`(s) to the parent `UITabBarController`. However, when I access `ParentViewController`, a reference is maintained, keeping my objects alive and are never being garbage collected.

Merely adding the following code to the child UIViewController's `ViewDidLoad` causes the memory leak.

```
var ni = ParentViewController.NavigationItem;
ni = null;
```

May parent UITabBarController never get's disposed because my child tabs reference it. Here is the output from HeapShot.

**WITH ACCESS TO `ParentViewController` FROM CHILD TABS**

[image: HeapShot with memory leak]

**WITHOUT ACCESS TO `ParentViewController` FROM CHILD TABS**

[image: HeapShot without memory leak]

Note that each memory snapshot was taking after doing the same except steps. Notice how the snapshot WITHOUT reference to ParentViewController how fewer instances, because that are being disposed. They are being disposed of so quickly, that I actually took the snapshot while I was viewing the controllers in question. The snapshot WITHOUT access to ParentViewController was taking while visiting another controller. In each case, the UITabBarController has been popped from the UINavigationController.

Any ideas why the CaseMediaItemsController maintains a reference to the CaseTabController when accessing ParentViewController?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a complete answer, look at http://xamarin.com/evolve/2013#session-0w86u7bco2

Basically, by referencing the parent in the child, you have a loop, and setting the NavigationItem to `null` is not enough, you have to `Dispose()` it as well. But you have to make sure you can, at this point in time, Dispose () the object.

```
var ni = ParentViewController.NavigationItem;
ni.Dispose ();
ni = null;
```

You can also go without keeping a strong reference to the NavigationItem, and if you need your `ni` variable for convenience, make it a `WeakReference<UINavigationItem>`. That'll allow it to be garbage collected.

```
WeakReference<UINavigationItem> ni;

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    ni = new WeakReference<UINavigationItem> (ParentViewController.NavigationItem);

    //Nothing else here.
}
```

You can then use `ni` like this:

```
if (ni.Target != null)
    Console.WriteLine (ni.Target.Title);
```

Comment: Brilliant! One follow up question though that I will create another SO question for. I had a similar issue with a MonoTouch binding. Using a weak delegate (NSObject), I using the controller as a delegate for a child object. This also created a circular reference which prevented collection. I had to, on "ViewPoppedFromNavigationController", set the  weak delegate to null. What about using WeakReference with monotouch bindings, specifically, models and delegates?

Comment: Are you using the WrapAttribute correctly ? http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries#Binding_Protocols

Comment: I have that. The only thing I am missing is ArgumentSemantic.Assign. Would that cause this issue?

Comment: I finally got around to implementing this, and it doesn't work. For one, there is no generic WeakReference. Also, the original problem still persists. "_parentNavigationItem = new WeakReference (ParentViewController);" Any ideas?

Comment: there is a generic WeakReference